# Create a Virtual machine using vmware vcenter VM template

Tags: java, vmware, vsphere, vcenter

I have a virtual machine template in VMware vCenter. I wanted to use that VM template, again and again, to create multiple virtual machines using Java API. I looked at site http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.wssdk.pg.doc_50/PG_Ch10_VM_Config.12.3.html for reference. Here I got the creation of VM with new gest os, But I wanted to create VMs using a specific template within vCenter.

Any code snippet to create VMs using VM template will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the "CreateVM_Task" method, you'll want to use the "CloneVM_Task" method.

Here's some example code: https://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-10818

Comment: thanks for pointing out the method name. here you can find a good example https://github.com/Juniper/vijava/blob/master/src/com/vmware/vim25/mo/samples/vm/VMClone.java

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a good example https://github.com/Juniper/vijava/blob/master/src/com/vmware/vim25/mo/samples/vm/VMClone.java

In my case, I had to add ResourcePool MOR to VirtualMachineRelocateSpec object.